# Average of odd cells?

Tags: c++

For an exercise I am doing, I am supposed to find out the average of the items contained in odd numbered cells of an array and some other things. Finding the average of the odd numbered cells in the only thing I'm having a problem with. Here is my code, what am I doing wrong? The final function is the odd numbered cells average function. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 1000;
int randoms[SIZE];
int sum2 = 0;
int top = 0;
int maximum = 0;

int highest(int randoms[]);
int findsum(int randoms[]);
int average(int randoms[], int sum);
int oddavg(int randoms[]);

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    int top = 0;
    int avg = 0;
    int oddaverage = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        randoms[i] = (rand() % 5000 + 1);
        cout << randoms[i] << setw(10) << " ";
    }

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "The sum of the values in the array is ";

    sum = findsum(randoms);

    cout << sum << endl;

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "The highest value in the array is ";

    top = highest(randoms);

    cout << top << endl;

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "The average of all of the numbers in the array is ";

    avg = average(randoms, sum);

    cout << avg << endl;

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "The average of all of the numbers in the odd cells is ";

    oddaverage = oddavg(randoms);
}

int findsum(int randoms[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        sum2 += randoms[i];
    }
    return sum2;
}

int highest(int randoms[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {

        if (randoms[i] > maximum)
        {
            maximum = randoms[i];
        }
    }

    top = maximum;

    return top; 
}

int average(int randoms[], int sum)
{
    int avg = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        avg = (sum / SIZE);
    }

    return avg;
}

int oddavg(int randoms[])
{
    int avg = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (randoms[i] / 2 == 1)
        {
            sum += randoms[i];
        }

    }
     avg = sum / SIZE;

     return avg;
}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to find the average of the numbers contained in odd-indexed cells, or the average of all odd-numbered values? Your code is trying to do the second, but what you explained was the first. (Your code also does the second incorrectly, as you don't want to divide by SIZE, you want to divide by how many things you found. Your if check is also incorrect)

Comment: You should also be accumulating into a `long`

Answer (score 3):

Doing the odd/even test (using modulo as many have suggested) in this case is totally redundant, since the loop doesn't do anything else.

You can just use a stride of 2 and start at the first odd element:

```
for (int i = 1; i < SIZE; i += 2)
{
   sum += randoms[i];
}
```

Then it's just a matter of dividing out by half of `SIZE`.  If that number is even, then there are `SIZE/2` odd numbers.  If it's odd, then there are `lbound(SIZE/2)+1` odd numbers.  Fortunately, you can take advantage of integer truncation and just do:

```
double avg = double(sum) / double((SIZE+1) / 2);
```

And you don't even have to worry about divide-by-zero =)

Comment: I really did not need the modulo. I've done this before but since I work with "i++" so much I completely missed that "i += 2" would do the trick. Thank you very much.

Comment: In case you missed it, I also hinted that your averages should probably be `double` (or `float`), not `int`.

Answer (score 1):

should be `if (randoms[i] % 2 == 1)`
Also you need to count the number of odd numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`randoms[i] / 2 == 1`, this will be true only when a cell value is `2` or `3`, this is certainly not what you need to do.

If you need to sum values of cells with odds index then it should be if `(i % 2 == 1)`. If instead you are looking for odd values (in any cell) it should be `if (randoms[i] % 2 == 1)`.

Mind that `%` is the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operation which returns the integer remainder of the integer division.

And since you are calculating an average you should divide by the found amount of elements, not by the total.

Answer (score 0):

```
int oddavg(int randoms[])
{
    int cnt = 0;
    int avg = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        if ( randoms[i] % 2 != 0 )
        {
            ++cnt; 
            avg += randoms[i];
        }

    }

     return ( cnt == 0 ? avg : avg / cnt );
}
```